# Testing login in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

I just started using Spring boot and Java Based Spring Configurations and I have a problem when trying to test security-related methods such as login and logout.

I have the following configurations in my project

SecurityConfig.java:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
        .and()
            .logout()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "j_spring_security_check", "/register", "/logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER");
    }
    @Autowired
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("guest").password("guest").roles("USER");
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
         return new RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

SecurityWebAppInitializer.java

```
@Order(1)
public class SecurityWebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer { }
```

RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java

```
public class RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
    SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

    if (savedRequest == null) {
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        return;
    }
    String targetUrlParam = getTargetUrlParameter();
    if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl() ||
            (targetUrlParam != null &&
                    StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParam)))) {
        requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        return;
    }

    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
}

public void setRequestCache(RequestCache requestCache) {
    this.requestCache = requestCache;
}
}
```

Now, I want to test the login process so my test class is the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SecurityWebAppInitializer.class, SecurityConfig.class })
public class SecurityTests {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(SecurityWebAppInitializer.class, SecurityConfig.class).addFilters(filterChainProxy).build();
}

@Test
public void thatLoginWithCorrectCredentialsWorks() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/j_spring_security_check")
            .param("j_username", "guest")
            .param("j_password", "guest")
    ).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
}
```

The above test returns the following error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :403
```

which says that the user is forbidden to access the login page. However I don't get why as I've configured in the SpringConfig that a user with the above credentials is allowed to login to my application. I would like to apologise in advance in case my question is silly but I am still trying to improve my knowledge on that framework as I am using it only for a couple of weeks.

EDIT: When I am using CURL to login I am getting the following error:

> {"timestamp":1401633376720,"error":"Forbidden","status":403,"message":"Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?"}

Comment: have you tried to run using ``.perform(post(...).with(csrf()``?  like suggested in http://spring.io/blog/2014/05/23/preview-spring-security-test-web-security

Comment: No I haven't but I it helped! Thank you very much!